# Xamarin Forms two content page in one

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, layout

I develop an app in Xamarin Forms.

I want to show two modes for my search results:

- Map mode
- List mode

I created two content page which works well.

However, every time I switch from one page to another it reloads everything.

So is it possible to embed two pages on one content page?

And I make it visible depneding on the mode.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: you can have multiple ContentViews in a single page.  Or you can use a MasterDetail

Comment: Thanks Jason. So if I transform my two content pages in content views and create a new content page with these two embeded and changing mode with  IsVisible is the good way?

Comment: thats what I would do

Comment: @dalton5 instead of setting IsVisible = true or false try having only one ContentView and switch the contentview with binding based on Command/Event. Because view invisible view still occupies that space